# Add an attachment knowing the file path but not the file name

Tags: vba, outlook, filenames, filepath

Using VBA, I've been trying to attach all JPG files in a directory to an email without knowing the exact filenames. I tried these lines of code:

```
.Attachments.Add "C:\Desktop\Attachments\" & "*.jpg"
.Attachments.Add "C:\Desktop\Attachments\*.jpg"
.Attachments.Add "C:\Desktop\Attachments" & "\*.jpg"
```

None of these worked. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like the following

```
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 For Each fsoFile In fso.GetFolder("C:\Desktop\Attachments").Files
   If fso.GetExtensionName(fsoFile) = "jpg" Then
     .Attachments.Add fsoFile.Path
   End If
 Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply an actual file path per the documentation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553.aspx

I think you could get each file path like this:

```
Dim fileName as String
fileName = Dir("C:\Desktop\Attachments\*.jpg")

Do While Len(fileName) > 0
    .Attachments.Add "C:\Desktop\Attachments\" & fileName
    fileName = Dir
Loop
```

Comment: Dir() only returns the file *name*, not the full path.  Code will fail if `C:\Desktop\Attachments\` is not the current directory

Comment: Thank you Tim. I updated my answer to append file name to the directory path.

Comment: Do I have to Dim fileName as String first?